# Roma Pass from Termini to Ciampino Airport

Tags: trains, tickets, airport-transfer, italy, cia

Can I use Roma Pass from Termini to Ciampino Airport or should I buy separate ticket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, but not directly from Termini

The Roma Pass is only valid on the bus services operated by ATAC. ATAC operates two services to Ciampino Airport. The first service is bus line 720, departing from  Laurentina Station on Metro line B. The second service is bus line 520, departing from Subaugusta Station and Cinecittà Station on Metro line A.

The Roma Pass is **not** valid on any other bus or train services to Ciampino Airport.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Roma Pass is also valid on the Metro lines mentioned. The best way would be to get the red metro line to Cinecittà and then change to the 520 bus.